# How to call a view controller from AppDelegate i.e. didFinishLaunchingWithOptions when using TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am new to iOS programming and do not know much about calling ViewControllers programatically. I am making an app for notes and I want to make it password protected. I used TabBarController and one of the tabs is for Settings (for enabling and disabling password protection). When app starts, I want to know that, is password protection enabled or disabled. And if it is enabled, I want to display a login screen (i.e. calling a different view controller). I think that I should do this from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in AppDelegate, but I dont know how to. I tried some of the ways, but failed. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code of what you tried ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry about the down votes - I don't think you deserve them. I had the same problem when I started iOS. This might help

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    //set NSDefaults when you set if password protection is needed - here you are checking to see if password enabling  exists

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL passwordExists;
    passwordExists = [defaults boolForKey:@"hasCompleted"];

    //jump to different view controller depending if BOOL is false or true
   //set names (ShowLogInScreenController) In StoryBoardID in the Interface Builder 
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard =[ UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *vc = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:passwordExists ? @"ShowLogInScreenController" : @"PasswordProtectionDisabledViewController"];
    UINavigationController *questionsNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    questionsNavigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    self.window.rootViewController = questionsNavigationController;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: It is working fine but the problem is that, now my tab bars are not visible.